# Кто-то может помочь расшифровать решение?

Tags: swift, функции, рекурсия

помогите расшифровать данную функцию понятным языком, понимаю что рекурсия, понимаю что идет сложение всех чисел, но не совсем понимаю на пальцах, будьте любезны, помогите пожалуйста

```swift
func caclulateDigitsSum(_ n: Int) -> Int {
    if (n < 10 ){
        return n
    }else {
        return (n % 10) + caclulateDigitsSum(_ : (n/10))
    }
}
caclulateDigitsSum(1234)
caclulateDigitsSum(1111)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция складывает все цифры в числе. Ее псевдокод:

```
func caclulateDigitsSum(_ n: Int) -> Int {
    if (в числе n только одна цифра - истина){
        возвращаем эту цифру
    }
    else {
        return (последняя цифра числа n) + caclulateDigitsSum(_ : (число n без последней цифры))
    }
}
```